# How to redirect a txt file to an html page with parameter and then call the content of that file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to write a little RewriteRule/RewriteCond but can't find the right resource/tutorial to understand how to achieve my goal. I don't have much knownledge about regex and rewriterules.

That goal is to be able apply a markdown library like [Strapdown](https://ndossougbe.github.io/strapdown/) to a markdown text file when opening it. My idea was :

- the user opens the markdown file at http://somedomain.com/myFile.md
- RewriteEngine get that you want to do that and redirect you to something like http://somedomain.com/markdown.html?myFile.md
- that markdown html page will fetch the content of the markdown file (the filename is in the url parameters) and apply the css library to whatever is loaded and injected in a div.

I think I understood how to redirect the md file to the html document with parameter :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*).md /markdown.html?md=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But then the markdown.html page that fetch the .md file is actually fetching the content of markdown.html itself (because of that rule).

So my idea then was to add some character at the end of the filename (like adding a '?' at the end of the file name : "myFile.md?") to be able to catch it in the rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(.*)\?$
RewriteRule ^(.*).md /markdown.html?md=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But it's not the way to go ... OR my last rewrite synthax is wrong and I don't understand why.

Any ideas ?

Thanks for the help !

Comment: If the request is for `/foobar.md` your rule `RewriteRule ^(.*).md /markdown.html?md=$1`  forwards it to `/markdown.html` preserving the URL path . What exactly is not working for you here?

Comment: That's the first part. The second part within markdown.html is trying to fetch the original .md file and use it to display. When fetching the content of the .md file the RewriteRule returns the markdown.html file instead of the .md file.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue was that I was trying to use an indetectable pattern (ie : finding '?' at the end of my url).

I changed it to try finding any number as parameter and it works

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([0-9])$

RewriteRule ^(.*).md /markdown.html?md=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The markdown.html file is now receiving the requested .md file as intended.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing OP's answer I came with some additional improvements in it, please have your htaccess rule file as follows.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^([0-9])$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.md /markdown.html?md=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

***Improvements done in OP's answer:***

- First escape `.md` on left side of RewriteRule to make it as a literal character else it may match strings like `amd` OR `bmd` etc.
- Second use `NC` flag in your RewriteRule to make it case in-sensitive so that either `.md` OR `.MD` both get match.
- Also additional suggestion in case your query string could have more than 1 digits in it, change your `[0-9]` to `[0-9]+` in RewriteCond section.